# Websocket logsSubscribe method doesn't provide the transactions

Tags: rpc, jsonrpc-api

I have an RPC node fully synchronized.

I can subscribe on "logsSubscribe" with the wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com endpoint:

wscat -c wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"method":"logsSubscribe","params":["all"]}

It will display all the transactions as expected.
But with my node, I get no transaction displayed (and no error as well, I'm subscribed):

wscat -c ws://localhost:8900

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"method":"logsSubscribe","params":["all"]}

Am I missing a parameter in the validator.sh ?

```
    --identity validator-keypair.json \
    --vote-account vote-account-keypair.json \
    --known-validator CMPSSdrTnRQBiBGTyFpdCc3VMNuLWYWaSkE8Zh5z6gbd \
    --known-validator 6WgdYhhGE53WrZ7ywJA15hBVkw7CRbQ8yDBBTwmBtAHN \
    --known-validator Ninja1spj6n9t5hVYgF3PdnYz2PLnkt7rvaw3firmjs \
    --known-validator GwHH8ciFhR8vejWCqmg8FWZUCNtubPY2esALvy5tBvji \
    --known-validator PUmpKiNnSVAZ3w4KaFX6jKSjXUNHFShGkXbERo54xjb \
    --known-validator DE1bawNcRJB9rVm3buyMVfr8mBEoyyu73NBovf2oXJsJ \
    --known-validator 7Np41oeYqPefeNQEHSv1UDhYrehxin3NStELsSKCT4K2 \
    --known-validator GdnSyH3YtwcxFvQrVVJMm1JhTS4QVX7MFsX56uJLUfiZ \
    --known-validator CakcnaRDHka2gXyfbEd2d3xsvkJkqsLw2akB3zsN1D2S \
    --known-validator 5D1fNXzvv5NjV1ysLjirC4WY92RNsVH18vjmcszZd8on \
    --known-validator 7XSY3MrYnK8vq693Rju17bbPkCN3Z7KvvfvJx4kdrsSY \
    --known-validator Ft5fbkqNa76vnsjYNwjDZUXoTWpP7VYm3mtsaQckQADN \
    --known-validator 9QxCLckBiJc783jnMvXZubK4wH86Eqqvashtrwvcsgkv \
    --log /home/tony/solana-validator.log \
    --ledger /mnt/ledger \
    --accounts /mnt/accounts \
    --rpc-port 8899 \
    --dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint4.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record \
    --full-rpc-api \
    --no-voting \
    --private-rpc \
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot have trailing `\` in the last line of your config.

Have you confirmed your validator is running and caught up? What server specs are you using here?

You may need to add account indexing https://docs.solana.com/validator/get-started/setup-an-rpc-node#account-indexing.

What is the response from the server when you connect WS, do other methods work?